# Database failed to create: Error: Could not change password - Neo4j Desktop 1.4.3

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I installed and used Neo4j 1.4.2 before, but when upgrading to 1.4.3, I can't create database. So, I uninstalled and installed again, it has same error. Error as below image.

[image]

This is my log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UmzSgEuKWieDL8InLLwYFy8tGDOgHIBK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Issues should be logged here: https://neo4j-desktop.canny.io/questions-and-general-feedback

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issues/bugs with the tool should be reported elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when upgrading to a newer version of Neo4j Desktop.  This what I did to fix it.  The problem is there are some settings on the older version that is causing the issue.

1. Neo4j Desktop folder for example: C:\Users<mylogin>.Neo4jDesktop\
2. Delete the ENTIRE folder
3. Install the newer version

Comment: I have done so before, but can't solve this problem